# How to get alphabetic listing x other posts, based on first letter post?

Tags: posts, query-posts, archives, sort

Let's say I have a `post` called "Hello World" and I am on that page... Let's say I have different posts like "Haaaa" and "Hoooo".... What I want to do is showing Haaa and Hooo in a different place (let us say the `sidebar`) if this "Hello World" post is being watched...

So in the sidebar we get this:

```
Heeee
Haaaaa
<div class="highlighted active"> Hello World </div>
Hoooooo
Hxxxxx
Hzzzzzz
```

Where do I start? I guess `<?php wp_get_archives('type=alpha'); ?>`, but how do I get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

For the solution you can use **if statement** 
as below
put it in your sidebar, it will **highlight** the current post title.

```
<ul>
<?php
$IDOutsideLoop = $post->ID;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li <?php if(is_single() && $IDOutsideLoop == $post->ID) print 'style="font-weight:bold";' ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Even wordpress provides for highlighting the current pages here,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting
it doesn't include to hightlight the specific post's title at sidebar.

I don't know if you are looking for static navigation , the below link might help you .
http://blog.huidesign.com/automatically-highlight-current-page-in-navigation-with-css-jquery/

Comment: How does this do it in an alphabetic order? Highlighting the current post isn't a problem (I guess, haven't looked on that one), but outputting 5 posts alphabetically before and after the current post is a big problem... I guess this does not do the thing I want.

Comment: I re-changed the codes as an array 'oder' => 'ASC' . hope it work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not do what I want. Let's say you are on single.php and you clicked a post called "Hello"... What I want it to do is that it outputs the 5 posts that are alphabetically before the post and 5 posts that are after the post (also alphabetically)... I appreciate your help, but it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: No one who can help?